# Interwoven TeamSite 6.7.2: How to regenerate all pages?

Tags: teamsite

Is it possible to regenerate all pages within Interwoven TeamSite 6.7.2? 
Simply selecting a folder and click on Actions -> regenerate page doesn't work. It gets the error message: "Not a generated file".

So is there a trick to regenerate through the folder hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

TeamSite will process whatever you passed as a parameter, be it file or folder. If it is not template-based, you will see that error. There is no way to recursively regenerate pages throughout a workarea natively.

I have written Perl scripts to traverse the filesystem, test each files extended attributes to see if it was template-based and regenerate the page if so. This is probably the easiest way to achieve mass regeneration.

If you must have this through the GUI, you can create a custom menu item that calls the above script.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this question was posted - it says Jan 25 but does not reveal the year, but TeamSite 6.7 has been EOL (end of life) for a few years by the vendor HP Autonomy.

As of this writing the latest version of the software is TeamSite 7.3.2, with version 7.4 right around the corner. The reason I mention about versions is because, the paradigm to create and render pages has undergone a complete change.

Pages are no longer "generated" and deployed. SitePublisher - now part of TeamSite allows pages to be authored using WYSIWYG tools.

That said, the old paradigm of "generating" pages is still backward compatible, but if you are planning to upgrade you may get more value from the system by using SitePublisher and LiveSite.

Comment: If there is no year indicated, it is the current year.

Answer (score 0):

run this command from the unix command line:

```
find /your/folder/startpoint -exec /path/to/iwregen {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message: "Not a generated file" that you are getting is because you are trying to select a folder since the contents of folders can be different some can be your actual pages while some can be a .pdf file, .txt file or any other extension files.

Please try to regenerate pages using these steps:

1. Double click on the folder to open in which your actual pages resides
2. After this try to select all the pages (not manually but there is option/checkbox on the UI as "select all" or "select").
3. Now, after selecting all just scroll down and see all the selected things whether they are actual pages and not something else. If they are not the pages then deselect only that particular file.
4. Now, click on "Actions" and regenerate the pages all at once. This will definitely work.

Please vote this solution if it is useful else please add your further issues/questions will try to help you with the best of my knowledge.

**Thanks!**